# Drunk man at the cliff problem: expected reward while staying alive? & unequal step size

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

There are several variations of this Drunk man (or a monkey) at the cliff problem.

I wonder what will be the expected sum of rewards if the drunk man gets paid while he stays alive.

The setup is like this.

At period zero, a man is standing at $n$ step from the edge of a cliff. In each period from period $1$, he takes independent steps; $k_1$ steps forward with probability $p$, $k_2$ steps backward with probability $q$, and he doesn't move with probability $1-p-q$. We assume $k_1,k_2>0$.

So, in each period, the random walk takes value of $-k_1$ w/p $p$, $k_2$ w/p $q$ and $0$ w/p $1-p-q$.

At the end of each period, if he's still alive, he gets paid \$1 as a reward. The future payoff is discounted by $\delta$. So, if he is expected to fall off the cliff after 3 periods, his sum of expected rewards is $$1+\delta+\delta^2.$$

My question is **what is the sum of the expected rewards?**

There are some relevant questions and answers. Here [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192753/1d-random-walk-with-different-step-sizes-in-each-direction), [Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153123/hitting-probability-of-biased-random-walk-on-the-integer-line), [Q3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349194/asymmetric-random-walk-with-unequal-step-size-other-than-1),... but because of the discount factor and the unequal step sizes, I can't figure out how to apply the identity... Any other approach or an answer?

Comment: Is there any limit to how far away from the cliff he can back up? If he starts at $-n$ and the cliff edge is at $0$, is the set of his possible positions bounded below?

Comment: If $T$ is the time at which he falls off, you want to find $E[1 + \delta + \dots + \delta^{T-1}] = \frac{1}{1-\delta}(1-E[\delta^T])$ using the geometric sum and linearity of expectation.  So you need the moment generating function of $T$.  As I recall this can be computed by martingale techniques though I don't know the answer off the top of my head.

Comment: @saulspatz, Thank you for your comment. Yes. he's initial position is $n>0$. Forward in the question means a step toward the cliff and backward means a step away from the cliff. I wasn't clear about that when asking the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: The money won't matter if he's guaranteed to fall off the cliff.... Jokes aside, are $k_1, k_2$ integers?

Comment: @VarunVejalla Haha, yes. And we may assume $k$'s are integers.

Comment: If $f(n) = E[\delta^T|Location=n]$ (with $f(n)=1$ if $n\leq 0$)  then for $n>0$ we have $f(n) = \delta(pf(n+k_1)+qf(n-k_2))$, so this becomes a linear difference equation, you can (in principle) find the roots of $r^{k_2} = \delta p r^{k_1+k_2} + \delta q$.

Comment: @Michael Does the linear difference equation approach still work even if $k_1$ and $k_2$ are not integers?

Comment: The same linear difference equation holds (replacing $n$ with $x$) and there are solutions of the type $ce^{rx}$, but now the boundary condition $f(x)=1$ for $x\leq 0$ seems more difficult to enforce, possibly requiring (infinitely?) many solutions for different $r$ values.