# Experiment by Bernoulli process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients

I have a question.
Assume I carry out an experiment by [Bernoulli process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process).
I repeat the tests until the number of successful outcomes
 
exceed the number of unsuccessful outcomes by ***m***.
What will be the distribution function ***f = f(m)*** of the number of tests?

Comment: @hardmath, sure, it's about Bernoulli process

Comment: @SangchulLee, the Pascal distribution it's "number (K) of successes in a sequence of independent and identically distributed Bernoulli trials before a specified (non-random) number (R) of failures occurs". But in my case R is random because depends on K. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: Oh, I must be severely sleep deprived to misread your problem. You are right.

Comment: Now it seems to me that your question boils down to the distribution of some hitting time of a biased random walk, because the process $$S_n = [\text{number of successes in the first }n\text{ tests}] - [\text{number of fails in the first }n\text{ tests}]$$ can ne realized by a biased random walk.

Comment: @SangchulLee interesting idea. But what is the final formula for f(m)?

Comment: It will involve Catalan numbers, as in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153123/biased-random-walk-on-line).