# Probability of throwing equal amount of heads&tails.

Tags: probability

I have a coin. When throwing there is a $p$ percent chance to get head and $(1-p)$ for tail. I throw it once and get head. What is the expected number of throws to get and even number of heads and tails for the first time.

Let $T$ be that event. Then I have

$E[T] = (1-p) + p(2 + E[T])$. Solving this for $E[T]$ gives $E[T] = (1+p)/p$.

Comment: Do you want to have an *equal* amount of heads and tails or an *even* amount? For example would 2 heads and 4 tails be an accepted result?

Comment: also, what is your actual question?

Comment: If $p > \frac12$ there is a non-zero probability that you _never_ get to an equal number of heads and tails. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153123/hitting-probability-of-biased-random-walk-on-the-integer-line