# How do you rule out the probability of 1 in this biased random walk problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

I am trying to work on [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153123/hitting-probability-of-biased-random-walk-on-the-integer-line), pasted below:

> Let's say we start at point 1. Each successive point you have a, say,
> 2/3 chance of increasing your position by 1 and a 1/3 chance of
> decreasing your position by 1. The walk ends when you reach 0.
>
> The question, what is the probability that you will eventually reach
> 0?

The selected answer solves the following equation

$$ r = \frac13 + \frac23 r^2$$

The roots are $r = 1$ and $r = 1/2$.

I'm struggling to understand how the answer rules out $r = 1$. I'm not sure what the $\tau_{n+1}$ meant in the answer. Alternatively, can someone explain to me how to rule out the root of $r=1$, with or without following the answer?